# When can one use logarithms to multiply matrices

Tags: linear-algebra

If $a,b \in \mathbb{Z}_{+}$, then $\exp(\log(a)+\log(b))=ab$. If $A$ and $B$ are square matrices, when can we multiply $A$ and $B$ using logarithms? If $A \neq B^{-1}$, should $A$ and $B$ be symmetric?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If $A$ and $B$ commute, i.e. $AB=BA$, then [the same identity holds](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Logarithm_of_a_matrix#Properties) for [an appropriate definition](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Matrix_exponential) of $\exp$ and $\log$. If $A$ and $B$ do not commute, then [things are much more complicated](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Baker%E2%80%93Campbell%E2%80%93Hausdorff_formula).

Answer (score 1):

When they commute, or: when they have the same eigenvectors, or if $AB=BA$